# References for Exercises on Abstract Simplicial Complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, self-learning, simplicial-complex

I am currently reading [*Combinatorial Algebraic Topology*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-71962-5) by Kozlov. I'm enjoying it a lot, however, it regretfully does not contain any exercises (it is more along the lines of lecture notes).

In the first chapter, he covers material related to abstract simplicial complexes, including: deletions, links, stars, wedges, simplicial joins, barycentric and stellar subdivisions, pullback and pushforward simplicial structures, etc.

These concepts go beyond what is covered about simplicial complexes in the standard introductory algebraic topology texts that I have seen (e.g., Hatcher or Munkres).

Are there any other references that cover these topics related to simplicial complexes that include exercises?

Comment: I would check out books about combinatorial commutative algebra, such as Miller, Sturmfels.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thanks! I think I looked at that book once and found it too difficult. Do you know what level of commutative algebra background is needed for that text, e.g., some/most/all of Eisenbud?